# I wanna make a dictionary has user_id's key & data

Tags: python, django, excel

I wanna make a dictionary has user_id's key & data.In views.py I wrote

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from .models import User

book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/excel1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

def build_employee(employee):
  if employee == 'leader':
     return 'l'
  if employee == 'manager':
     return 'm'
  if employee == 'others':
     return 'o'

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
  rows = sheet.row_values(row_index) 
  is_man = rows[4] != ""
  emp = build_employee(rows[5])
  user = User(user_id=rows[1], name_id=rows[2], name=rows[3], 
              age=rows[4],man=is_man,employee=emp)
  user.save()

files = glob.glob('./user/*.xlsx')

for x in files:
    if "$" not in x:
      book3 = xlrd.open_workbook(x)
      sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)
      cells = [
    ]
      data_dict = OrderedDict()
      for key, rowy, colx in cells:
         try:
            data_dict[key] = sheet3.cell_value(rowy, colx)
         except IndexError:
            data_dict[key] = None

      data_dict_key ={}
      data_dict_key['user_id'].update(data_dict_key)
```

But when I run this code,error happens

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/XXX/testapp/app/views.py", line 164, in <module>
    data_dict_key['user_id'].update(data_dict_key)
KeyError: 'user_id'
```

I really cannot understand why this error happens.
When I print out  data_dict,it is

```
OrderedDict([('user_id', '1'), ('name', 'Blear'), ('nationality', 'America'), ('domitory', 'A'), ('group', 1)])
```

My ideal dictionary is

```
dicts = {
    1: {
        user_id: 1,
        name_id: 'Blear',
        nationality: 'America',
        domitory: 'A',
        group: 1,
    },
    2: {
    },
}
```

How should I fix this?Should I use for statement?

I rewrote my codes by seeing the comments,now views.py is

```
data_dict_key ={}
for x in files:
    if "$" not in x:
      book3 = xlrd.open_workbook(x)
      sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)
      cells = [
    ]
      data_dict = OrderedDict()
      for key, rowy, colx in cells:
         try:
            data_dict[key] = sheet3.cell_value(rowy, colx)
         except IndexError:
            data_dict[key] = None

            if data_dict['user_id'] in data_dict_key:
               data_dict_key[data_dict['user_id']].update(data_dict)
               continue
            data_dict[data_dict_key['user_id']] = data_dict
```

Comment: In the end of the loop you are assigning an empty dict to the data_dict_key  `data_dict_key = {}` . So, there is no 'user_id' in the data_dict_key. And you are trying to do this `data_dict_key['user_id'].update(data_dict_key)`.  That is the reason why you are getting "KeyError".

Comment: @sherlcode13 thx ur comments.I can understand what u r saying.But to fix this,what should I write this?

Comment: @sherlcode13 I wrote     
  for i in data_dict_key.items():
          data_dict_key['user_id'].update(data_dict)
but i cannot get my ideal dictionary.

Comment: If I'm right you are trying to get your ideal dictionary as output ?

Comment: @sherlcode13 what is the meaning of ur message?

Comment: I got it now. Do initialize your data_dict_key outside your `for x in files:` loop and in the end write this `if data_dict['user_id'] in data_dict_key:  data_dict_key[data_dict['user_id']].update(data_dict) continue` in the next line outside if statement  `data_dict_key[data_dict['user_id']] = data_dict`

Comment: @sherlcode13 I added codes by seeing ur comments,but KeyError: 'user_id' error happens.Did i misunderstand ur comments?I updated my question.

Comment: you did the typo error `data_dict_key[data_dict['user_id']] = data_dict` last line should be this. You wrote this `data_dict[data_dict_key['user_id']] = data_dict`

Comment: I rewrite my code,but i got same error like
if data_dict['user_id'] in data_dict_key:
KeyError: 'user_id'

Comment: @sherlcode13 How can I fix this?

Comment: Just move the last four line outside the `for key, rowy, colx in cells:` loop

Comment: @sherlcode13 I deleted for key, rowy, colx in cells:, but in below try-catch error happens because key, rowy, colx is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @sherlcode13 I cannot understand only ur comments,so could u write ur thinking code in answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You for loop should be this. Hope this will helps.

```
data_dict_key ={}
for x in files:
    if "$" not in x:
      book3 = xlrd.open_workbook(x)
      sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)
      cells = [
    ]
      data_dict = OrderedDict()
      for key, rowy, colx in cells:
         try:
            data_dict[key] = sheet3.cell_value(rowy, colx)
         except IndexError:
            data_dict[key] = None

      if data_dict['user_id'] in data_dict_key:
         data_dict_key[data_dict['user_id']].update(data_dict)
            continue
      data_dict_key[data_dict['user_id']] = data_dict
```